# Format rows in styled dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, sklearn-pandas

```
y=TableA.reset_index().rename({'index':''},axis=1)
format_two={ y.columns[1]: "{0:,.2f}",
           y.columns[2]: "{0:,.2f}",
          }

xx = y.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues',axis=1).format(format_two).hide_index()
```

I'm trying to make the first two rows have int type with 0 trailing decimals. But struggling to pass rows into format_two variable. How do i go about this?
[image: Styled DF with 3 rows]

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
f = lambda x: f'{int(x):,d}' if int(x) == x else f'{x:,.2f}'
format_two={ y.columns[1]: f,
             y.columns[2]: "{0:,.2f}",
           }
```

Output (note that I only format the first column):

[image]

Comment: Incredible. TYSM.